# How to "select" a navbar button when anywhere in a section

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, navbar

I'm setting up a basic mobile site using jQuery Mobile. I have a basic navbar with 3 navigation buttons. Each button takes the user to a specific section of the site, where they can then run a search and drill down to details pages with further details. I'd like the button representing the current "section" to be highlighted / marked active, even if the user is not on the particular page that the button links to.

As an example, the navbar would be something like this:

```
<div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-theme="b" data-id="myHeader">        
    <div data-role="navbar">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="BookSearch.cfm" data-icon="book">Book Search</a></li>
            <li><a href="MovieSearch.cfm" data-icon="movie">Movie Search</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div><!-- /navbar -->
</div><!-- /footer -->
```

Then when the user clicks on "Book Search", and it takes them to the search page, the "Book Search" icon should be "active". (Currently it's not.) Additionally, when the user searches for a book and gets a list of results, and then chooses a specific book to view further details on, etc., the "Book Search" icon should remain "selected" so that it's clear which section of the site is currently in use.

I am coding this in ColdFusion, and the only solution I have thought of is to create a list of pages for each section and check if the current page is in the list; if so, manually set `class="ui-btn-active ui-state-persist"` for the relevant navbar button. Are there any other, better ways to accomplish this?

Comment: If you change the class click the link, what would make it change to another class?

Comment: @mplungjan - sorry, I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: what is DOM relationship of section button to links shown? Doubt you need to hard code arrays if there is a DOM relationship such as href exists in a specific grouping index

Comment: If were to hook up a click event handler that changed for example the background colour of the link, what would remove that class if not a click and your own code? I mean if we just change the class of the clicked link, it should STAY changed until you changed it yourself right?

Comment: when viewing _details_ of a book, do you move to a `cfm` file or a _hash page_?

Comment: @mplungjan jQM removes it https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/blob/master/js/widgets/navbar.js#L59-L61

Comment: One solution I can think of, is going through jQM's navigation history and read URL of each record. Last record that matches _BookSearch_ or MovieSearch_ gets the active class.

Comment: so set a cookie/localstorage when clicking the link and set the class to match the cookie on each load

Comment: Cant you send data to the next CFM file like href="BookSearch.cfm?activebutton=booksearch" and then send it back to the main page and make the button active???